# How can I statically link my MFC extension DLL?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

I have an MFC extension DLL that I've written. It contains derived classes of MFC controls (e.g. replacements for CButton etc) and also contains bitmap resources.

I wanted to create a static library - mainly because I do not want the code seperated into a DLL. However, I found that even though it is possible to add resources to a static library, I couldn't get the Class Wizard to work. As a result I created a DLL instead and now I want to find a way of statically linking my DLL into my application.

Can anybody help please? I am still using MSVC++ 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify - what I would really like to know is how to create static .LIB file that contains resources, and classes via the Class Wizard.

Update: I got around this by creating a seperate (common) .rc file that I include in my main applications. Works a treat.